# Jest - Redux action creator with React Native Animated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I'm trying to test a redux action with Jest. I'm running into an issue when it comes to the mocking the Animated library with React Native. Here's my code (condensed):

```
// action.js
const loginAction = () => {
  Animated.timing(animation, {
    toValue: 0,
    duration: 600
  }).start(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' }); 
  });
}

// mock-setup.js
jest.mock('Animated', () => {
  return {
    timing: jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        start: jest.fn()
      };
    }),
    Value: jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        interpolate: jest.fn()
      };
    })
  };
});
```

In my test, I'm attempted to compare the dispatched actions, but I can't seem to get my test to go inside the callback of the `start` function. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer! My `Animated` mock needed to look like this:

```
jest.mock('Animated', () => {
  return {
    timing: jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        start: callback => callback()
      };
    }),
    Value: jest.fn(() => {
      return {
        interpolate: jest.fn()
      };
    })
  };
});
```

The `start` function is passed a function, so I just needed to give my mocked version a way to run the function.